# How to apply a function to certain columns in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Assume i have this table:

```
t: flip `col1`col2`x_col1`x_col2!(`a`b`c`d;`aa`bb`cc`dd;1 2 3 4;11 22 33 44)

col1    col2    x_col1  x_col2   x_col...
a         aa         1      11
b         bb         2      22
c         cc         3      33
d         dd         4      44
```

Where i could have an arbitrary number of columns called x_col1..100 etc.
How can i say for all columns that matches "x_col*" multiply by 10?

```
col1    col2    x_col1  x_col2   x_col...
a         aa        10     110
b         bb        20     220
c         cc        30     330
d         dd        40     440
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Can use something like:

```
q)@[t;c where (c:cols t) like "x_col*";*;10]
col1 col2 x_col1 x_col2
-----------------------
a    aa   10     110
b    bb   20     220
c    cc   30     330
d    dd   40     440
```

edit: if looking to multiple by x_col1 for example:

```
@[t;c where i;*;(sum i:(c:cols t) like "x_col*")#enlist t`x_col1]
col1 col2 x_col1 x_col2
-----------------------
a    aa   1      11
b    bb   4      44
c    cc   9      99
d    dd   16     176
```

Comment: Thank u very much Michael. May I ask an additional question. Is is possible to replace the atom 10 with something like x_col1 a vector?

Comment: No problem. It is but it requires you to shape the vector to same format of the columns you are manipulating. For example in this case you need to take vector twice(make a matrix) as you are manipulating 2 columns:
@[t;c where (c:cols t) like "x_col*";*;2#enlist t`x_col1]
It might help you see it better by just doing the indexing first then playing with that result:
10*@[t;c where (c:cols t) like "x_col*"] works but 
10 20 30 40*@[t;c where (c:cols t) like "x_col*"] will not

Comment: Another way you could go about the problem is to write an update statement in functional form where you get the column names you want to manipulate dynamically and then use xcol1 within the functional form as the multiplier.

Comment: The second part can be simplified to ```@[t;c where(c:cols[t])like"x_col*";t[`x_col1]*]```

Answer (score 2):

Although I like Michaels answer more, for completeness the functional form would be:

```
q)c:c where(c:cols t)like"x_col*"

q)![t;();0b;c!flip(10*;c)]
col1 col2 x_col1 x_col2
-----------------------
a    aa   10     110
b    bb   20     220
c    cc   30     330
d    dd   40     440

q)![t;();0b;c!flip(*;`x_col1;c)]
col1 col2 x_col1 x_col2
-----------------------
a    aa   1      11
b    bb   4      44
c    cc   9      99
d    dd   16     176

/using functional might allow for more flexibility (where clauses etc)
q)![t;enlist(=;`col1;enlist`d);0b;c!flip(*;`x_col1;c)]
col1 col2 x_col1 x_col2
-----------------------
a    aa   1      11
b    bb   2      22
c    cc   3      33
d    dd   16     176
```